# ¿Como dividir Excel en diferentes hojas?

Tags: python, pandas

estoy tratando de dividir un archivo Excel en diferentes hojas según un parámetro del tipo de especie de planta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he realizado un código pero este solo me sirve para dividirlo en diferentes archivos con los nombres de cada especie

```
    import pandas as pd

    df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Copicompu\Desktop\Libro2.xlsx')
    
    for i in df.species.unique():

       df2=df[df['species']==i]

       df2.to_excel(f"{i}.xlsx",index=False)
```

como puedo hacer para que en lugar de crear diferentes archivos cree diferentes hojas dentro del mismo excel??
ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gustavo.

Sólo un apunte, no creo que sea bueno que reescribas sobre el archivo Excel que lees al principio. Veo más seguro crear otro a parte.

Creo que porías probar esto:

```
#Creas un objeto para meter los datos en un archivo Excel, 
#así como el archivo en Excel en cuestión
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Flowers.xlsx', engine='xlswriter')

#Un diccionario en el que se almacenan nombres asociados a dataframes
df_dict = {}

for i in df.species.unique():
    globals()[i] = df.loc[df['species']==i]
    
    df_dict.update({str(globals()[i]) : globals()[i]})
    
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(globals()[i]), index=False)
    #Probablemente esta parte se pueda simplificar
writer.save()
```

Espero que te sea útil.